# Making changes to a database entry in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm building a web app that displays database information from a table of gym equipment.  So far, I am able to produce a webpage, with a dropdown list of all the items, and the information auto-populates the fields for information.

How do I make it so somebody viewing the website can add, delete, and modify table entries with just a few buttons like add/update/delete/submit?

Here is the C# code I have produced so far:

```
public partial class Inventory : System.Web.UI.Page
{
Item currentInventory = new Item();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateInventory(0);
}



private void UpdateInventory(int index)
{
    DataView inventoryTable = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)inventoryTable[index];

    currentInventory.fac_ID = row["fac_ID"].ToString();
    currentInventory.inv_Quantity = row["inv_Quantity"].ToString();
    currentInventory.inv_Purchase_Date = row["inv_Purchase_Date"].ToString();


    lblFacilityID.Text = currentInventory.fac_ID;
    lblQuantity.Text = currentInventory.inv_Quantity;
    lblPurchaseDate.Text
= Convert.ToDateTime(row["inv_Purchase_Date"]).ToShortDateString();
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateInventory(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex);
}
}
```

And here is the .aspx code I have so far:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeFile="Inventory.aspx.cs" Inherits="Inventory" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"   DataTextField="equip_Name" DataValueField="equip_ID" AutoPostBack="True"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="    <%$      ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Inventory.*, Equipment.* FROM      Equipment INNER JOIN Inventory ON Equipment.equip_ID = Inventory.equip_ID">   </asp:SqlDataSource>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Facility:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFacilityID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Purchase Date:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPurchaseDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />
<asp:DetailsView ID="ManageProducts" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px">
</asp:DetailsView>


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements are simple, and you just want to allow users to manage data.

Dynamic Data Web site using ASP.NET analyzes the application's data model and generates Web pages dynamically based on the data in the data model. These auto-generated Web pages provide the capability to display, insert, delete, and edit data for each table.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469.ASPX

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this would probably be beyond the scope of stackoverflow.

I've worked a lot in MVC and webforms aren't too different. What you'll want to do is somehow take those changes from the webpage (using AJAX perhaps?) and then implement the changes in what's hopefully a different class from what you're already written.

My suggestion would be to look at an MSDN article rather than hoping for what would be a 3 page answer here.